# Ansible: second lineinfile task doesn't do anything

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to add entries to 2 ACLs in `named.conf` with ansible's `lineinfile` module, but it seems that only the first task is being run.

The configuration is:

```
acl operacao {
        192.168.1.33;
        192.168.2.29;
        10.10.0.0/24;
        };

acl monitoring {
        10.10.0.0/24;
        };
```

So I created a playbook with 2 tasks:

```
    - name: add to operacao acl
      lineinfile:
        path: "/etc/named.conf"
        line: "        10.2.2.0/24;"
        insertafter: "acl operacao"
      register: acl_op

    - name: add to monitoring acl
      lineinfile:
        path: "/etc/named.conf"
        line: "        10.2.2.0/24;"
        insertafter: "acl monitoring"
      register: acl_mon
```

When run with the `--check` flag, it correctly predicts where the lines will be inserted:

```
TASK [add to operacao acl] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
--- before: /etc/named.conf (content)
+++ after: /etc/named.conf (content)
@@ -21,6 +21,7 @@
 };

 acl operacao {
+        10.2.2.0/24;
         192.168.1.33;
         192.168.2.29;
         10.10.0.0/24;

changed: [dnshost01]

TASK [add to monitoring acl] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
--- before: /etc/named.conf (content)
+++ after: /etc/named.conf (content)
@@ -27,6 +27,7 @@
         };

 acl monitoring {
+        10.2.2.0/24;
         10.10.0.0/24;
         };
```

However, when run without the `--check` flag, it only shows changes on the first task, the second doesn't run:

```
TASK [add to operacao acl] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
--- before: /etc/named.conf (content)
+++ after: /etc/named.conf (content)
@@ -21,6 +21,7 @@
 };

 acl operacao {
+        10.2.2.0/24;
         192.168.1.33;
         192.168.2.29;
         10.10.0.0/24;

changed: [dnshost01]

TASK [add to monitoring acl] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [dnshost01]
```

This is always run with `--flush-cache`.

What is happening here? Am I misunderstanding something, or is ansible bugged?

I'm running ansible 2.9.27 on RHEL8.5 / python 3.6.8. This behaviour happens for RHEL6 and RHEL7 hosts.

Comment: As an alternative to Zeitounator's fine comment, if your config file allows it you could make the first IP and its 2nd copy differ by whitespace or an EOL comment, as in `line: "    10.2.2.0/24; # line 2"`

Comment: I suspected something like that was happening. It makes perfect sense now.

Comment: @Zeitounator would you mind writing this as an answer so that I can give proper attribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstood how the module works.

The `insertafter` option gives an indication of where to insert the line **if it does not already exist**.

When your run in check mode, since the line is not inserted with your first task (as you are just checking), you still have no match in the second task so ansible reports it would make the change.

For the above to work you would have to use a regex, match multiple lines on each block to see if it exists and insert with back-reference to retain the existing content. This in itself will probably be a pain to finalize and maintain. Your current and future co-workers (or even yourself in a few weeks...) might have a hard time figuring out what was done exactly (complex regex operation are not self explanatory...).

And since `lineinfile` does not support multi-line regex anyway, you would have to go through the [`replace` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/replace_module.html) which will probably bring other challenges in your context.

Complex usage of `lineinfile` or `replace` to deal with existing content in-place is usually a sign that you should start using a [template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html).